# Trouble Deleting Firebase Reference When Using UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I am making a feed that uses Firebase in my app and I am having trouble creating something that allows the user to delete a post. The way that I am attempting to do it is by creating a UITableViewCell (called 'Post') to handle each cell. I created a protocol so I could show an alert in the parent view controller when the image is tapped and made the cell it's own delegate in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. The alert asks if you are sure you want to delete the post. I want the post to delete if the user says yes, however it is not doing that. When the user taps the image to delete the post, the reference to the firebase location is saved to NSUserDefaults. That value is retrieved when the user hits 'yes' from the alert and I call removeValue()...however, the value is not being removed. Below is what I am talking about.

```
protocol Alert {
    func showAlert()
}

class PostCell: UITableViewCell {
var delegate: Alert?
...
func deleteTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    defaults.setObject(String(self.postRef), forKey: "PostRef")
    defaults.setObject(String(self.likeRef), forKey: "LikeRef")

    self.delegate?.showAlert()

    //self.postRef.removeValue()
    //self.likeRef.removeValue()

}
...
}


//This is the parent ViewController
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as? PostCell {
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.request?.cancel()

        var img: UIImage?

        if let url = post.imageURL {
            img = FeedVC.imageCache.objectForKey(url) as? UIImage
        }

        cell.configureCell(post, img:  img)

        return cell
    } else {
        return PostCell()
    }

}

func showAlert() {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Post?", message: "Are you sure you want to delete the post?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let no = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    let yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { alert in

        self.postRef = Firebase(url: String(self.defaults.valueForKey("PostRef")))
        self.likeRef = Firebase(url: String(self.defaults.valueForKey("LikeRef")))

        print(self.postRef)
        print(self.likeRef)

        self.postRef.removeValue()
        self.likeRef.removeValue()

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
    alert.addAction(no)
    alert.addAction(yes)

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

If I call removeValue() in the deleteTapped() method that is in the UITableViewCell then the values get deleted but that happens before the alert pops up to asks the user if they are sure of deleting the post. However, nothing happens when I do removeValue() in the showAlert() ('yes' pressed) method. I printed the value of the references I am trying to delete and they are correct, but for some reason Firebase is not getting the command to delete them.

**Answer**

So I figured out what I needed to do here. I realized that I needed to pass in a post object into my protocol function like this:

```
protocol Alert {
    func showAlert(post: Post)
}
```

Then I needed to add another variable (I called it myPost) of type Post! in the PostCell (which is the name of my UITableViewCell) like this:

```
var myPost: Post!
```

Then I needed to get the value of myPost by going to my cellForRowAtIndexPath method in my viewController. I added:

```
cell.myPost = post
```

where post is the object for that given cell.

Then, in my deleteTapped method (In my UITableViewCell) I changed self.delegate?.showAlert() to:

```
 self.delegate?.showAlert(myPost)
```

Here, I am basically just passing in the variable that I declared in my protocol.

Finally, I went over to my viewController again to my showAlert() method. I needed to change showAlert() to showAlert(post: Post) which was declared in my protocol. Then I just created my references and removed values in the 'yes' handler like so:

```
        let postRef: Firebase = DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.childByAppendingPath(post.postKey)
        let likeRef: Firebase = DataService.ds.REF_USER_CURRENT.childByAppendingPath("likes").childByAppendingPath(post.postKey)

        postRef.removeValue()
        likeRef.removeValue()
```

Comment: You should not be using NSUserDefaults for this task! It's really designed to keep track of... well, defaults: like the background window color or which location the user wants the weather for. Also, there's really no reason to store the reference while waiting on the user to select Delete: Yes or No. You already know which one they tapped so when returning Yes from the modal window, delete it. Also, remember that Firebase is asynchronous so you should call the removeValue() using a block and inside that block, remove it from your storage array and then reload the tableView.

Comment: I'm not sure we are on the same page here. How am I supposed to delete it when postRef is a value that is in the UITableViewCell subclass and showAlert() is in the parent viewcontroller? So after the user clicks 'Yes', there is no reference to postRef in that controller.

Comment: postRef should not be in the tableViewCell. Your tableView should be populated from a datasource, such as an array, and really only showing the textual data the user sees. Your tableView also knows what row/object that was selected. So when the user selects a row, and clicks OK to delete, you then get the data from that row (in the array), remove it from firebase and remove it from the array. Then reload the tableView.

Comment: I am using tap gestures on the clickable items in the tableView, hence the protocol/delegate I used. The cells themselves are not clickable because I don't want user interaction on the cell itself other than to scroll. Therefore, I am not using the cellForRowAtIndexPath method and I do not know what row/object is selected other than from what is in my UITableViewCell. Also, I don't need to remove it from my array because that is updated automatically when there is a post (added or deleted) on the server.